# Modify gulpfile to read html files in subfolder and spit them out to build folder

Tags: javascript, html, gulp

I have been working on modifying this relatively simple gulpfile/project: https://github.com/ispykenny/sass-to-inline-css

The first issue I had was to update to gulp v4, but I've also tried to store variables for my src and destination folders which is a bit easier to control. So now my gulpfile looks like this:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const inlineCss = require('gulp-inline-css');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
const plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
const del = require('del');

const srcFolder = './src'; // TODO tidy this up once working
const buildFolder = srcFolder + '/build/'; // Tidy this up once working

const src = {
    scss: 'src/scss/**/*.scss',
    templates: 'src/templates/**/*.html'
}

const dest = {
    build: 'build/',
    css: 'build/css'
};

function processClean() {
    return del(`${buildFolder}**`, { force: true });
}

function processSass() {
    return gulp
        .src(src.scss)
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dest.css))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream())
}

function processInline() {
    return gulp
        .src('./*.html')
        .pipe(inlineCss({
            removeHtmlSelectors: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/'))
}

function processWatch() {
    gulp.watch(['./src/scss/**/*.scss'], processSass);
        gulp.watch(srcFolder).on('change', browserSync.reload);
        gulp.watch(distFolder).on('change', browserSync.reload);
}

const buildStyles = gulp.series(processSass, processInline);
const build = gulp.parallel(processClean, buildStyles);

gulp.task('clean', processClean);
gulp.task('styles', buildStyles);
gulp.task('sass', processSass);
gulp.task('inline', processInline);
gulp.task('build', build);
gulp.task('watch', processWatch);
```

But I am now wanting to create lots of template files, store them in a subfolder and have gulp spit out each file into the destination folder. if I have index.html, test1.html etc in the root it works fine.

I tried modifying this:

```
function processInline() { return gulp.src('./*.html')
```

To this:

```
function processInline() { return gulp.src(src.templates) // should equate to 'src/templates/**/*html'
```

Now I'm seeing this error in the console:

`ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\myuser\pathToApp\emailTemplates\src\templates\build\css\style.css'`

In the head of index.html in the root is this:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="build/css/style.css">`

I actually don't really care about the css file as the final output should be inline (for email templates). But I cannot get my head around why this is happening.

Does gulp create the css file and then read the class names from there? *EDIT*, Ah I guess it must because it has to convert the sass to readable css first before stripping out the class names and injecting the inline styles.

Years ago I worked with grunt a fair bit, and webpack, but haven't done much with gulp.

I hope it is obvious, but if you need more information just let me know.

Comment: Try this instead: `templates: 'src/templates/**/*.html`  Note the `.`

Comment: Apologies. I did notice this already and have corrected it in my local code (and also edited my question) this is not the issue unfortunately.

Comment: I am certain it is to do with the relative positioning of the template files to the css which gets extracted, trying to see if gulp will work with absolute file paths, although relative would be much better.